# Export image for documentation

Tags: export, google-earth-engine

I want to export my classified image to drive in GEE, for presenting in a document.
I have used this code.

```
Export.image.toDrive({  
  image: classified,  
  description: 'classified_basin_with_points', 
  scale: 30, 
  region: geometry,  
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',    
});
```

But the exported image showed no color whereas my cassified layer have 4 clssifying color on it. How can i get a colorful image that will cover my classifying layer color?

Comment: who answeres this wuestions...ive been asking for help as well

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/164139)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Google Earth Engine documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting), to get an image exported as it appears in Google Earth Engine, you need to create Visualization images.

> Exporting images as they appear in the Code Editor
>   To export imagery as rendered on screen in Earth Engine, create visualization images as demonstrated in the Visualization images and the Compositing and Mosaicking sections. Since the Code Editor uses the 'EPSG:3857' CRS, specify a CRS of 'EPSG:3857' in the export to get an image in the same projection as that displayed in the Code Editor map. See the section on configuring image exports for details on specifying the resolution and coordinate system of the output.

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_visualization#visualization-images

> Visualization images
>
> Use the `image.visualize()` method to convert an
>   image into an 8-bit RGB image for display or export. For example, to
>   convert the false-color composite and NDWI to 3-band display images,
>   use:
>
> `// Create visualization layers.`
>
> `var imageRGB = image.visualize({bands: ['B5', 'B4', 'B3'], max: 0.5});`
>
> `var ndwiRGB = ndwiMasked.visualize({min: 0.5,   max: 1,   palette: ['00FFFF', '0000FF'] });`